# What style of beer is Carling Black Label

Tags: lager, beer-styles, commercial

It’s obviously a Lager, but that only describes the yeast. In what style of beer is Carling Black Label made. I drink just about only craft beer, but if I pushed for what I think is a great commercial beer. The Canadian developed Carling Black label is actually a really decent beer. But to this day I don’t know what style of beer is actually is.

Answer (score 2):

This beer goes WAY back and has distant roots in Sweden. There are probably differences depending on where you source it from. Carling in the USA is actually owned by Molsen Coors.

The beer can be classified quite correctly and accurately as “lager”. If we are being truly pedandic, lager(ing) is a process rather than a yeast, although of course there are yeasts that are best suited for this treatment.

Lager is the style and Carling Black Label is an exemplar product.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest style is called [Export Lager or Helles Exportbier](http://Probably%20the%20closest%20style%20is%20called%20Export%20Lager%20in%20the). It's a generic lager style of beer without a lot of distinction.

Comment: It has quite a distinctive taste though. Do you know what Grain that is from?

Comment: Something like this brewed in Canada is probably very similar to BudMilloors in that it's mostly barley with some rice to lighten up the flavors and make it cheaper to produce. I would be surprised if it was 100% malted barley.